# DB2 SQL - Remove duplicates where some duplicates are valid

Tags: sql, db2, duplicates, ibm-midrange

I would like to delete duplicate records from XRDK/ENAUDFP_RK, I have tried a 'where exists' clause with the below SQL but this deleted all records in the file rather than just the duplicates.

To give a little background; the issue here is a duplicated daily sales file - it is entirely possible for a store to sell more than 1 of the same item per day, therefore some of the duplicates are not actually duplicates, only every other row is a duplicate.

I.e. if a store sold 2 of them same item, there would be 4 records - 2 genuine sales, 2 duplicates.

This is the SQL I used to highlight the duplicates;

```
SELECT * FROM                                                     
  (SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER (                                      
   PARTITION BY                                                   
   INCOMP, INTTYP, INTDAT, INMDAT, INSDAT, INTCCY, INERAT, INDEPT,
   INSTYL, INCOLO, INMATL, INSIZE, INFIT, INVENX, INEAN, INSKU,   
   INBATC, INPSIT, INFSIT, INTSIT, INSUPP, INPONO, INSCCY, INREF1,
   INREF2, INREF3, INSREF, INDREF, INUNIT, INRETL, INCOST, INLRET,
   INLCST, INSCST, INFGRP, INFCAT, INFSEC, INTGRP, INTCAT, INTSEC,
   INSTEN, INSTEV, INSVAT, INPLUL, INSVTF, INSFOR, INSFOV, INVCOD,
   INTO01, INSP01, INSP02, INSP03, INFNUM, INFDES, INRCOD, INRC01,
   INRC02, INRC03, INRC04, INRC05, INRC06, INRC07, INRC08, INRC09,
   INRC10, INRV01, INRV02, INRV03, INRV04, INRV05, INRV06, INRV07,
   INRV08, INRV09, INRV10, INDELD, INCUID, INIREF, INSOUR, INSNUM)
   AS RN, ENAUDFP_RK.*                                            
   FROM   XRDK/ENAUDFP_RK) AS A                                   
 WHERE RN in('2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '12')
```

Comment: So the store/item combo is UNIQUE...?

Comment: No. The reason behind this is that you can have discressionary discounts or staff discounts etc. that are applied at PoS, so effectively the tendered price for a store/item (and the associated other values with that figure, like VAT, margin etc.) can differ between transactions for the same store/item.

This is why my partion by clause uses all fields in the table because effectively this is the level the record becomes UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rrn for this in DB2

```
DELETE FROM XRDK/ENAUDFP_RK f0
WHERE rrn(f0) in (
 SELECT RW FROM                                                     
 (SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER (                                      
 PARTITION BY                                                   
 INCOMP, INTTYP, INTDAT, INMDAT, INSDAT, INTCCY, INERAT, INDEPT,
 INSTYL, INCOLO, INMATL, INSIZE, INFIT, INVENX, INEAN, INSKU,   
 INBATC, INPSIT, INFSIT, INTSIT, INSUPP, INPONO, INSCCY, INREF1,
 INREF2, INREF3, INSREF, INDREF, INUNIT, INRETL, INCOST, INLRET,
 INLCST, INSCST, INFGRP, INFCAT, INFSEC, INTGRP, INTCAT, INTSEC,
 INSTEN, INSTEV, INSVAT, INPLUL, INSVTF, INSFOR, INSFOV, INVCOD,
 INTO01, INSP01, INSP02, INSP03, INFNUM, INFDES, INRCOD, INRC01,
 INRC02, INRC03, INRC04, INRC05, INRC06, INRC07, INRC08, INRC09,
 INRC10, INRV01, INRV02, INRV03, INRV04, INRV05, INRV06, INRV07,
 INRV08, INRV09, INRV10, INDELD, INCUID, INIREF, INSOUR, INSNUM)
 AS RN, f1.*, rrn(f1) RW                                            
 FROM   XRDK/ENAUDFP_RK f1) AS A                                   
 WHERE A.RN in('2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '12')
 )
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, tested it and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the duplicates you can delete them. My example shows it with a table "e2"

```
delete from (
  select * from (
      select rownumber() over (partition by .....) as rn,
             e2.* 
        from e2)
   where  mod(rn, 2) = 0 )
```

The mod in my example is used to identify every second row.
You have bneen on the right track with the rownumber()  idea already.

Comment: This seems interesting, due to the 'mod' function - I have not heard of this, but the syntax of the statement doesn't seem to be correct.

I added in the partition by information you elipsed out, but there's no mention of my file name afterwards and as such the statement doesn't work. I am more than capable of figuring out getting it to work but the suggestion from Esperento57 worked a treat.